# creating custom annotation in spring mvc and getting httpservletrequest object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I want to create custom annotation and put that annotation on method level using `HttpServletRequest` object. so far I did this:

Created annotation

```
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Mapping
public @interface CheckSession{
    boolean isAuthenticate() default false;
}
```

created handler class

```
@Component
public class CheckSessionClass implements HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler,HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter arg0,
            ModelAndViewContainer arg1, NativeWebRequest arg2,
            WebDataBinderFactory arg3) throws Exception {
        logger.info("......MY ANNOTATION CALLEDD.....resolveArgument");
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter arg0) {
        logger.info("......MY ANNOTATION CALLEDD.....supportsParameter");
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object retutnValue, MethodParameter returnType,
            ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
        CheckSession annotation;
        annotation=returnType.getMethodAnnotation(CheckSession.class);
        if(annotation.isAuthenticate()){
logger.info("......got request is aurhenticated..true");
        }else{
            logger.info("......got request is aurhenticated..false");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter arg0) {
        logger.info("......MY ANNOTAION CALLEDD.....supportsReturnType");
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

created a controller to invoke annotation like this.

```
@Controller
public class MyController 
{
    @RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    @CheckSession(isAuthenticate=true)
    public ResponseEntity<String> mymethod (HttpServletRequest request)
    {
            ///my code here....
    }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml file is configured as auto component scan , but still my annotations class is not getting called.can anyone let me know my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to configure the interceptor in your application context (in spite of the auto-scan):

```
<bean id="checkSession" class="CheckSessionClass"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <ref bean="checkSession"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me ** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interceptor type not supported **

Comment: It's not an interceptor.

Comment: I've got the same issue: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interceptor type not supported...  Any tips?

Comment: @LorenzoSciuto Can you try using the defaultHandler instead of interceptors? (I've updated the answer)