# Assign value to variable based on its annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In my current spring project, I am looking for a way to assign some value for the attributes of some of the my POJO classes.

This feature is similar to the use of the annotations `PathVariable` and `ModelAttribute` for some parameters in the methods of a controller: when a parameter is annotated with one of this annotations, the own system read the value for this parameter and assign to the variable, without need use `<variable> = <value>`.

In my project, I have some POJO class like this:

```
class Class {

    private <type> <attribute>

    public <type> get<attribute>() {
        return <attribute>;
    }

    public void set<attribute>(<type> <parameter>) {
        <attribute> = <parameter>;
    }

}
```

if add an annotation to the attribute (for instance: @Setting), when I create a new instance of this class, the system should read a value in a file and assign to the variable.

Anyone can tell me how to do this?

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782673/creating-custom-annotation-in-spring-mvc-and-getting-httpservletrequest-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring @PropertySource & @Value annotations. I mean something like this:

```
 @Value("${sourceLocation:c:/temp/input}")
    private String source;

    @Value("${destinationLocation:c:/temp/output}")
    private String destination;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public void readValues() {
        System.out.println("Getting property via Spring Environment :"
                + environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));

        System.out.println("Source Location : " + source);
        System.out.println("Destination Location : " + destination);
```

There is a good up-to-date [blogpost here](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-propertysource-value-annotations-example/)

Comment: Is it possible use for parameter of `@Value` the return value of a existing method from other class of my application, instead of `${...}`?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html according to javadoc of value A common use case is to assign default field values using "#{systemProperties.myProp}" style expressions. So i think you need an initialize method which is annotated '@PostConstruct', and get the other class object as autowired. You can check @PostConstructor annotation.